# Yet another Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning question

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Yes this question has been asked many times! No, I have still not been able to figure out how to run this boolean filter without generating the Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning warning.

```
for x in range(len(df_A)):
    df_C = df_A.loc[(df_A['age'] >= df_B['age_limits'].iloc[x][0]) &
                    (df_A['age'] <= df_B['age_limits'].iloc[x][1])]

    df_D['count'].iloc[x] = len(df_C) # triggers warning
```

I've tried:

- Copying df_A and df_B in every possible place
- Using a mask
- Using a query

I know I can suppress the warning, but I don't want to do that.

What am I missing? I know it's probably something obvious.

Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure I follow, but it doesn't make sense to me that you do `df_A.loc` based on a different data frame, i.e. `db_B`.

Comment: IIUC, the problem is to select the column of `df_D` and then use `iloc`. I would say if before the loop, you do `pos_col_D = df_D.columns.get_loc['count'] ` and then in the loop do `df_D.iloc[x,pos_col_D ] = len(df_C)` should remove the warning.

Comment: @Ben.T that worked. If you want to put it as an answer I will accept. Would be awesome if you can explain why it works too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more details on why you got **SettingWithCopyWarning**, I would suggest you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/9274732). It is mostly because selecting the columns `df_D['count']` and then using `iloc[x]` does a **"chained assignment"** that is flagged this way.

To prevent it, you can get the position of the column you want in `df_D` and then use `iloc` for both the row and the column in the loop `for`:

```
pos_col_D = df_D.columns.get_loc['count']
for x in range(len(df_A)):
    df_C = df_A.loc[(df_A['age'] >= df_B['age_limits'].iloc[x][0]) &
                    (df_A['age'] <= df_B['age_limits'].iloc[x][1])]

    df_D.iloc[x,pos_col_D ] = len(df_C) #no more warning
```

Also, because you compare all the values of `df_A.age` with the bounds of `df_B.age_limits`, I think you could improve the speed of your code using [`numpy.ufunc.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), with `ufunc` being [`greater_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.greater_equal.html) and [`less_egal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.less_equal.html#numpy.less_equal), and then `sum` over the axis=0.

```
#Setup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'age': [12,25,32]})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'age_limits':[[3,99], [20,45], [15,30]]})

#your result
for x in range(len(df_A)):
    df_C = df_A.loc[(df_A['age'] >= df_B['age_limits'].iloc[x][0]) &
                    (df_A['age'] <= df_B['age_limits'].iloc[x][1])]
    print (len(df_C))
3
2
1

#with numpy
print ( ( np.greater_equal.outer(df_A.age, df_B.age_limits.str[0])
         & np.less_equal.outer(df_A.age, df_B.age_limits.str[1]))
        .sum(0) )
array([3, 2, 1])
```

so you can assign the previous line of code directly in `df_D['count']` without loop `for`. Hope this work for you